# OrderBy with custom comparer performs much slower than default comparer

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sorting, icomparer

In the following example, can someone explain why the version using the custom comparer is so much slower than the other method?

I was expecting them to be similar as they're essentially doing the same thing?

Is it because the custom comparer version has to call two methods? the Compare and then the double.CompareTo? where as I guess the first version is only calling the double.CompareTo? but would that really account for such a big difference?

```
public class Program
{
    public class ColumnComparer : IComparer<Row>
    {
        public ColumnComparer(int column)
        {
            Column = column;
        }

        public int Column { get; }

        public int Compare(Row x, Row y) => x.Values[Column].CompareTo(y.Values[Column]);
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public int Index { get; }

        public List<double> Values { get; } = new();

        public Row(int index)
        {
            Index = index;
        }
    }

    public class Sort
    {
        private readonly List<Row> _rows;

        public Sort()
        {
            _rows = new List<Row>();
            var r = new Random(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                var row = new Row(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < 32; ++j)
                {
                    row.Values.Add(r.Next(0, 1000));
                }

                _rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void Sort1()
        {
            _rows.OrderBy(x => x.Values[8]).ToArray();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void Sort2()
        {
            var comparer = new ColumnComparer(8);
            var sort2 = _rows.OrderBy(e => e, comparer).ToArray();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<Sort>();
    }
}
```

Edited to include performance measuring :

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sort1 | 111.6 ms | 1.46 ms | 1.79 ms |
| Sort2 | 343.5 ms | 4.01 ms | 7.42 ms |

Edit :

Added metrics including Sort3 (@dbc)

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sort1 | 112.0 ms | 0.90 ms | 0.85 ms | 13.35 MB |
| Sort2 | 344.4 ms | 2.27 ms | 2.12 ms | 13.35 MB |
| Sort3 | 138.7 ms | 0.64 ms | 0.57 ms | 17.17 MB |

Comment: I am just using the built in Stopwatch class in Release. I know its not the best way to measure due to warmup, repeat, average etc., but the difference is so big, I don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: Updated with BenchmarkDotNet metrics

Comment: It is not surprising that sorting by comparing `x.Values[Column].CompareTo(y.Values[Column])` is 3X slower than sorting by comparing two doubles.  The custom sort requires two `List<double>` index lookups and fetch from memory while the default sort just requires a single `double` comparison.

Comment: What happens if you precompute the sort value by doing `_rows.Select(row => (row, value : row.Values[8])).OrderBy(p => p.value).Select(p => p.row).ToArray()`?

Comment: Related: [Why is List<T>.Sort using Comparer<int>.Default more than twice as fast as an equivalent custom comparer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439976/why-is-listt-sort-using-comparerint-default-more-than-twice-as-fast-as-an-eq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not at all surprising that your custom sort is 3x slower than the default sort.  When LINQ evaluates

```
_rows.OrderBy(x => x.Values[8]).ToArray();
```

The class [`EnumerableSorter<TElement, TKey>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/52bd95caa3563bb889548e489762388d6842dca4/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L348C27) constructs an arrays of `double []? _keys;` (since `TKey` is `double` in this case) by calling the `keySelector` method **once per item**.  It then sorts that array in-place using the [default `double` comparison](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/52bd95caa3563bb889548e489762388d6842dca4/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Double.cs#L258) (by way of [`GenericComparer<double>.CompareTo()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/52bd95caa3563bb889548e489762388d6842dca4/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Comparer.cs#L58)), which will get called roughly **`n log(n)`** times.  Since nothing is boxed or unboxed, this should be quite fast.

Conversely, when you do:

```
_rows.OrderBy(e => e, comparer).ToArray()
```

`EnumerableSorter<TElement, TKey>` will construct a `Row []` array, then call your custom sort method `x.Values[Column].CompareTo(y.Values[Column])` **`n log(n)`** times.  Since this method is much more complex than the default double comparison method and involves multiple pointer dereferences and list lookups, it's not surprising that it takes substantially longer.

This is an example of a general rule that, when sorting a large collection using a complex sort method is insufficiently performant, **it can pay to precompute as much of the work done by the comparer as possible in the key selector.**  Which is exactly what you are doing with your `x => x.Values[8]` key selector.

If you need access to the precomputed key values after the sort finishes, you could project to a `ValueTuple<TElement, TKey>` before sorting, e.g.:

```
[Benchmark]
public void Sort3()
{
    var sort3 = _rows
        .Select(row => (row, value : row.Values[8])) // Precompute the value
        .OrderBy(p => p.value)                       // Compare the value
        .Select(p => p.row).ToArray();               // And extract the original row.
}
```

I don't have access to `BenchmarkDotNet` currently, but a demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ND6vE) shows that `Sort3()` is only 15-25% slower than `Sort1()` when sorting a list of 45,000 rows:

```
Average time per repetition for 100 reps of Sort1: 12.2888 ms.
Average time per repetition for 100 reps of Sort2: 37.8331 ms (207.87% slower).
Average time per repetition for 100 reps of Sort3: 14.6479 ms (19.20% slower).
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the metrics to include Sort3 for anyone curious.

Comment: My understanding is that the `.Select.OrderBy.Select` should not have any advantage over the simple `.OrderBy`, which precomputes the value anyway. The `keySelector` delegate is invoked only once per element in the sequence.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - the advantage of `.Select.OrderBy()` in comparison to `OrderBy()` is that the former allows for an additional `keySelector` which allows the tuple to be projected to a double, which in turn allows the builtin system double comparer to be used.  Absent that you would need to write a tuple comparer that compares the double value.  It's a bit of extra nuisance that I avoided with the first `Select()`.

Comment: What I am comparing is the `.Select(row => (row, value : row.Values[8])).OrderBy(p => p.value).Select(p => p.row).ToArray();` with the `.OrderBy(row => row.Values[8])`. Both are using the default comparer. The first seems like additional overhead for no apparent reason.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Hmm, seems you're right.  I was thinking that `_rows.OrderBy(x => x.Values[8]).ToArray();` was returning an array of doubles and so the tuple was needed to regenerate the original `Row`.  I'll update my answer later today.

Comment: I think I see what @TheodorZoulias means now. Sort3 is just a less efficient way of getting the same result as Sort1, and offers no benefits over Sort1.

Comment: @volvic - it's less efficient in the linear term, but identical in the `n log(n)` term.  `Sort2()` is less efficient in the `n log(n)` term. I updated the answer and left in `Sort3()` as a way to export the computed key to some downstream use, such as a subsequent `OrderBy()`.